# how to find bad points in a linear interpolation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, boost

I have a set of points and I know that:

1. All of them are from 0-255
2. They are in increasing format (so Point[0] <= Point[1])
3. They are repressing a line (with some noise).

But there are some points that behave badly. I need to detect that points. What is the fastest way to do this?

In general I can get the first one and last one and find the line formula and then calculate error for each point and if the error is too high, I mark that point as bad point.

Is there any better way (faster and more accurate)?

Is there any library that can help (I am using OpenCV and Boost).

Comment: Can you define "behave badly"? What if The first and last line are actually the "bad points"? What makes you think picking these two are the best approach?

Comment: yea, taking the 1st and the last point might be a bad idea , thus: [fitLine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline)

Comment: @berak fitLine seems a good solution. How can I find points which are not good? The points that deviate a lot from the actual line?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking first and last points, you should calculate [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and measure the distance of points from that trend line instead. It could be that your first/last point behaves badly.

Comment: How can I find the distance of a point to a line? What is the fastest way?

Comment: @mans You could just evaluate the line function f(x)=k*x+a at the x-coordinate of the point and check if abs(k*point_x+a-point_y) exceeds some threshold (k and a being line coefficients). This isn't "perpendicular" distance, but I guess good enough in your case.

Comment: What is this distance?

Answer (score 0):

run a loop through them, if p[i] < p[i-1], then it's behaving badly.

i dont know why you mention lerp, it sounds unrelated. lerp functions can't return wrong results.